# MacOS: Pass filepath into node via cli

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, command-line-arguments, npm-scripts

Say I have the following npm script:

```
"test": "node $FILE"
```

How would I pass an absolute path to it via cli?

Example:

```
FILE="pwd + filename" npm run test
```

which should result in:

```
node /Root/Subfolder/filename
```

I'm on MacOS using NodeJS 14.

Comment: There is really no need to set environment variables. Consider passing the filepath as an argument instead. For instance; **1)** Define your script in _package.json_ as `"test": "node"` **2)** Then run; `npm test -- "subfolder/filename"` _(Note: the `--` between the `npm test` command and the filepath is required)_. This way works cross-platforms unlike your current accepted answer which works on _*nix_ platforms only (Linux, macOS, etc..).

Comment: @RobC ah i see. I'll try that instead. Forgot about that

Comment: Sure, my suggested solution is actually more akin to the title of your post, i.e. _"Pass filepath into node via cli"_ and it utilizes builtin npm features. Whereas your accepted answer actually; **1)** Sets an environment variable named `FILE` prior to running the `npm test` command **2)** Then references the environment variable in _package.json_ - all done with bash features, which of course will fail on Windows which uses `cmd` as the default shell and not `sh` as per _*nix_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, you have a script file e.g. `./scripts/test.js`.

The script config would be like this:

```
"test": "node ${FILE}"
```

And, the command to run it would be:

```
$ FILE="$(pwd)/scripts/test.js" npm run test
```